# Accessing .properties file in webcontent folder form servlet project

Tags: java, servlets

I'm having some issues with loading a (.properties) file from the webcontent folder in my servlet.
The solutions that I've found don't seem to work. I'm getting an exception when trying to read the file. Below my folder and package structure and the parts of code.

What am I doing wrong?

**Webcontent folder structure**

```
WebContent  
- WEB-INF  
- languages  
  -- language.properties  
- ....
```

**Package structure**

```
package x.y.z.aa  
- Servlet.java  
package x.y.z.ab  
- PropertyLoader.java
```

**Servlet.java code**

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {      
    super.init(config);  
    servletContext = this.getServletContext();  
    PropertyLoader = new PropertyLoader(servletContext);  
}
```

**PropertyLoader.java**

```
 public PropertyLoader(ServletContext context) {  
    super();  
    try{  
      properties.load(context.getResourceAsStream("/languages/language.properties"));  
      System.out.println(languages.get("test"));  
    } catch (Exception e){  
      System.out.println("Error reading properties file");  
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }
}
```

---

Sorry. I forgot to instantiate the Properties instance variable. Thanks for the tip regarding HTTP access when it's in its current location. This should be resolved when I put it under the WEB-INF Folder?

Comment: It'll have been a trivial `NullPointerException`.

Comment: verify whether `servletContext` is not null

Comment: @Bozho: the OP posted an answer that he didn't initialize `properties`. So it was `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about changing your properties file location. At the current location it's contents can be accesed through a simple HTTP GET request (as in http://host:8080/AppContext/languages/language.properties ), which could be considered as a security issue.

Also, if you could post the exception you get, could be from more help to find what's happening with your code.

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question. This should have been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

It is advisable to place such files in `WEB-INF`. Then the following should work, if the file is there (actually it should work in your current setup as well). Just make sure the file is well-formed - i.e. that it is a real properties file.

```
properties.load(context
    .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/languages/language.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually you put things like this in the WEB-INF folder. Unless you really want it to be accessible via HTTP for some reason.